# mvc 5 authentication - where is the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, visual-studio-2013

I've created a new web application in Visual Studio 2013. I removed the connection string from the web config and ran the application. I was able to register and login on local host. There is no mdf in the App_Data folder. I turned on "show All Files".

Where is the database?

Comment: show code, show config

Comment: You want me to show you visual studio scaffolding?

Comment: there is nothing in your web.config file?

Comment: Its the default code that comes in every new [edit: asp.net web application] project minus the connection string

Comment: thanks, could also post code where a call is made to DB?

Comment: EF6 uses LocalDB by defualt: you can find your files following this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework 6 uses [LocalDB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx) by default.

It stores your database under you user's folder with the name of your `DbContext` so

```
C:\Users\user-name\yourcontextname.mdf
```

You can read more about how the files are stored and how to access LocalDB from the SSMS from this article: [LocalDB: Where is My Database?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx)